# Sigenv when starting jdeveloper on Fedora 20 Linux

Tags: java, linux, eclipse

> **jdeveloper/jdev/bin/jdev -clean  Oracle JDeveloper 12c 12.1.3.0.0
>   enter code here  Copyright (c) 1997, 2014, Oracle and/or its
>   affiliates. All rights reserved. Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
>   warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=320M; support was removed in 8.0
>   #
>
> ## A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> ## **
>
> ## SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00000034f2e64910, pid=22705, tid=140507802855168
>
> #
>
> ## JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_25-b17) (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
>
> ## Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
>
> ## Problematic frame:
>
> ## C  0x00000034f2e64910
>
> #
>
> ## Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
>
> #
>
> ## An error report file with more information is saved as:
>
> ## /home/sysadm/workspace/Middleware/1/jdeveloper/jdev/bin/hs_err_pid22705.log
>
> /launcher.sh:
>   line 1207: 22705 Aborted                 (core dumped) ${JAVA}
>   "${APP_VM_OPTS[@]}" ${APP_ENV_VARS} -classpath ${APP_CLASSPATH}
>   ${APP_MAIN_CLASS} "${APP_APP_OPTS[@]}" Error: JDeveloper can't
>   recognize the JDK version

Answer (score 2):

I found this link

http://www.java-n-me.com/2013/07/jdeveloper-12c-is-not-starting.html

../Middleware/1/jdeveloper/jdev/bin/jdev

put in jdev start script this line

unset GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID

works!

Comment: ...consider to accept your (own) answer, @asass314! ;)